# Constraining Wala's Class Hierarchy?

Tags: java, bytecode, static-analysis

I want to generate the IR for some java bytecode. The project I am using is using [Wala](https://github.com/wala/WALA) as the static analysis tool for other reasons. One of the steps that I need to do is to create class hierarchy for a given scope of interest. Now it seems that the creation of the class hierarchy is an expensive process, thus minimizing it is desirable specially if I need to call it repeatedly.

I tried to narrow the scope of the class hierarchy by using `AnalysisScopeReader.readJavaScope(...)` where I specify a scope file that contains only a single entry, mainly the class that I want to analyse, which is loaded using `Application` loader. However that does not seem to work because I get an error that `com.ibm.wala.ipa.cha.ClassHierarchyException: failed to load root <Primordial,Ljava/lang/Object> of class hierarchy`. It seems that Wala is expecting to have the `jre.jar` in the scope file too, so it can find `Ljava/lang/Object`. However that is problematic, because if I added with line to the scope file, the creation of class hierarchy will include so many classes that I am not going to use, and which i'd rather not spend time or memory on.

It seems that people have been struggling with this issue [here](https://github.com/wala/WALA/issues/288) too but was never resolved.

To be concrete, here is what I do

```
scope2 = AnalysisScopeReader.readJavaScope(somePath, null, urlcl);
cha = ClassHierarchyFactory.makeWithRoot(scope2);
```

I really do not want/need to create class hierarchy in my analysis, I am not using any call graph analysis. I need only to create the IR for a single class that I am analyzing without having to pay for creating hierarchy of classes which I am not going to use. Or at least, I want the class hierarchy is contains a single file that I am currently analyzing.

It seems that `ClassHierarchyFactor.makeWithRoot()` almost works except that it still requires `Object` class to use for missing superclasses, which means that I need to add the java lang class hierarchy into the analysis.

The solution here ([How to get rid of the unrelated classes when using WALA to analyze Java bytecode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842245/how-to-get-rid-of-the-unrelated-classes-when-using-wala-to-analyze-java-bytecode)) seems to be a hack rather than a fix.

I am not sure if there is a way to do that, can anyone help? Is there anyway in Wala that I can get ssa IR for a single class without having to construct a class hierarchy that is so big java lang class hierarchy?

Many thanks!

Comment: When writing a question about a 3rd party library, you should start with naming and linking the library instead of assuming that every reader immediately knows what you are talking about. It might be worth adding why you are using that analysis library when you are not interested in its features. There are plenty of bytecode processing libraries not building an expensive type hierarchy.

Comment: @Holger, thank you very much for replying. I have updated the question with your comments. Really, the project I am working on is using Wala for so long, but now that I am trying to use it as per class analysis, it seems to be not a very good analysis tool for simple purposes. Do you know if there is anyway around not building a huge class hierarchy, yet still get an IR? Much appreciated !

Comment: Well, that obviously depends on your actual requirements on the IR. But doesn’t `AnalysisScope` have filter methods?

Comment: @Holger, yes it does! I think it gives the wrong impression, because it requires at least the jar that contains the ```Object``` class. And if I add that line, i'll be constructing class hierarchy for the java lang, which I do not want. Without adding this jar for ```Object``` class, I get the above error from Wala, complaining that it can't find the ```Object``` class.

Comment: @Holger, I should say that ```AnalysisScope``` does make a scope for the analysis but I think it is useful for user defined or a third library classes, but from what I see, it at least requires the jar where ```Object``` class resides.

Answer (score 0):

The following should get you minimal class hierarchy for a single `targetClass`

```
  private ClassHierarchy getClassHierarchy(Class<?> targetClass) {
    AnalysisScope scope = getAnalysisScope(targetClass);
    return ClassHierarchyFactory.makeWithRoot(scope);
  }
```

where

```
private AnalysisScope getAnalysisScope(Class<?> targetClass) {
    String targetFile = targetClass.getResource(targetClass.getSimpleName() + ".class").getFile();

    FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getFileSystem(URI.create("jrt:/"));
    byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(fs.getPath("modules", "java.base", "java/lang/Object.class"));
    Path path = Path.of(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "target", "test-classes", "Object.class");
    Files.write(path, bytes);

    AnalysisScope scope = AnalysisScope.createJavaAnalysisScope();
    scope.addClassFileToScope(ClassLoaderReference.Primordial, path.toFile());
    scope.addClassFileToScope(ClassLoaderReference.Application, new File(targetFile));

    return scope;
}
```